# How can I show two polynomials common roots with a given matix and resultant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, roots, resultant

How can I show, that if $u:= ax + b$ and $v:= x^2 + cx + d$ ,  $(a, b, c, d ∈ \mathbb{R})$ polinoms have common root, if and only if $det(A[u, v]) = 0$, where
$A[u, v] =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & 0\\
0 & a & b\\
1 & c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ .

Should I do this with resultant? And how? I'm looking for guidance, not the exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

$\det A[u,v]=0$ if and only if there exists a nonzero vector $X$ such that
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & 0\\
0 & a & b\\
1 & c & d
\end{pmatrix} X =0.$$
If $\alpha$ is a common root, then
$X=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha^2\\ \alpha \\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ works. Now if such an $X$ exists can you prove that there is a common root?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, this was a huge hint.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

$u$ and $v$ have a common root if and only if there are non-zero polynomials $\alpha$, with $\deg \alpha \leq \deg u -1$, and $\beta $, with $\deg \beta \leq \deg v -1$, such that

$$ \beta(x) u(x) + \alpha(x) v(x) = 0. \; \; (1)$$

(We can see this by denoting the common factor by $t$, non-constant polynomial, such that $u = tu_1$ and $v=tv_1$. We can then choose $\beta = v_1$ and $\alpha = -u_1$.)

In our example, $\alpha(x) = e$ and $\beta(x) = fx+g$, respectively.

The null polynomial $(1)$ can be rewritten as

$$ (fa+e)x^2 + (fb+ga +ec)x + (gb +ed) = 0, $$
which is equivalent to the system of equations in unknowns $ f, g, e$
$$ a\cdot f + 0\cdot g + 1\cdot e =0 $$
$$ b\cdot f + a \cdot g + c\cdot e = 0 $$
$$ 0\cdot f + b\cdot g + d \cdot e = 0 $$
Solution $ f, g, e$ is non-trivial if and only if $\det A = 0$.

**Brute force solution:** For $a\not= 0$, the common root can only be

$$-\frac{b}{a}. $$

In this case:

$$ v\left(-\frac{b}{a} \right) = 0,$$

which is equivalent to:

$$ b^2 -cba +da^2 =0.$$

One can then verify that:
$$\det A  = b^2 -cba +da^2. $$

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Comment: I'm glad it helped.